# Firebase Error --> code=permission-denied

Tags: angular, firebase

I have a simple collection reference in a service

```js
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
          this.itineraryCollection = firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection(`itinerary/${user.uid}/itineraryList`);
        }
      });
```

I'm calling this service OnInit

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedInUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.dataSvc.getItineraries()
    .get()
    .then( itineraryListSnapshot => {
      this.itineraries = [];
      itineraryListSnapshot.forEach(snap => {
        this.itineraries.push({
          id: snap.id,
          activities: snap.data().activities,    
          userId: snap.data().userId
        });
      });
    });

    // this.itineraries = this.dataSvc.getUserItinerary();
    console.log('logged in user add itin page', this.itineraries);
  }
```

But I keep getting the following error on page initialization:

```js
vendor.js:49548 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

I'm not sure what my database rules in firebase should be but I've tried a bunch of different rules:

```js
      match /itinerary/{userId} {
            allow read; 
            allow write;
      }
      
            match /itinerary/{userId}/itineraryList {
            allow read; 
            allow write;
      }
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you paste complete rules, not just a part of it? and also if firestore structure shown, it's much easier to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit your firefunction rules as follows,

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

try the above code it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Issue in firebase database rules.

You can replace these rules with :-

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2021, 4, 26);
    }
  }
}
```